# is a two-dimensional array to store pay codes and rates only displaying the paycodes then calculate the gross pay by the amount of hours

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2015

The application should store the pay codes and rates in a two-dimensional array. It should also display the pay codes from the array in a list box. The btnCalc_Click procedure should display the gross pay, using the number of hours worked and the pay rate corresponding to the selected code.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain
Const strPROMPT As String = "Please enter the amount of hours"
Const strTITLE as string = "Hours Amount"
Private strPayGrades(,) As String = {{"A07", "8.50"},
                                   {"A10", "8.75"},
                                   {"B03", "9.25"},
                                   {"B24", "9.90"},
                                   {"C23", "10.50"}}

Dim strHours As String
Dim dblGross As Double
Dim dblHours As Double
Dim dblGradeWage As Double
Dim intR As Integer
Dim intIndex As Integer
Dim strGradeWage As String


Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' fills list box with codes and then selects the first item

    For intR = 0 To 4 Step 1
        lstCodes.Items.Add(strPayGrades(intR, 0))
    Next intR

    lstCodes.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    ' calculates and displays the gross pay

    strHours = InputBox(strPROMPT, strTITLE)
    If strHours Like "##" Or strHours Like "#" Then


        Double.TryParse(strHours, dblHours)
        Integer.TryParse(lstCodes.SelectedIndex.ToString, intIndex)

        strGradeWage = strPayGrades(intR + intIndex, 1)
        Double.TryParse(strGradeWage, dblGradeWage)


        dblGross = dblHours * dblGradeWage
        lblGross.Text = dblGross.ToString("c0")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid format please try again",
                        "Try Again",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        strHours = InputBox(strPROMPT, strTITLE)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub lstCodes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCodes.SelectedIndexChanged
    lblGross.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

change strGradeWage = strPayGrades(0 + intIndex, 1)

strGradeWage = strPayGrades(0 + intIndex, 1)

looks like that was the problem